# How do I define a persistent storage claim for my deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I get this error message:

```
Deployment.apps "nginxapp" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "nginx-claim"
```

Now, I thought deployment made a claim to a persistant storage, so these are det files I've run in order:

First, persistant volume to /data as that is persistent on minikube (https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume

metadata:
  name: small-pv

spec:

  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi

  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce

  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain

  storageClassName: local-storage

  local:
    path: /data

  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - my-node
```

Then, for my nginx deployment I made a claim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim

metadata:
  name: nginx-claim

spec:
  storageClassName: manual

  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce

  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Before service I run the deployment, which is the one giving me the error above, looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment

metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginxapp

  name: nginxapp

spec:
  replicas: 1

  volumes:
    - persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: nginx-claim

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginxapp

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginxapp

    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/data/www"
          name: nginx-claim
```

1. Where did I go wrong? Isnt it deployment -> volume claim -> volume?
2. Am I doing it right? The persistent volume is pod-wide (?) and therefore generally named. But the claim is per deployment? So thats why I named it `nginx-claim`. I might be mistaken here, but should not bug up this simple run doh.
3. In my deployment i set `mountPath: "/data/www"`, this should follow the directory already set in persistent volume definition, or is building on that? So in my case I get `/data/data/www`?

Answer (score 1):

Try change to:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nginx-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage  # <-- changed
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

At your deployment spec add:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginxapp
  name: nginxapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginxapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginxapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-claim
          mountPath: "/data/www"      
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-claim  # <-- added
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nginx-claim
```

Comment: Hi @gohm'c, I actually saw that my pvc was "yellow". Changing storageClassName solved that but my deployment still gets the same problem: invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "nginx-claim"

Comment: Your `volumes` is at the wrong place. See the updated answer.

Comment: Ah, that seems to work... but there is another problem now. I deploys but there is an error in my deployment: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node had volume node affinity conflict. Lol. Google states something about timezones, but this is a local minikube setup. Neither did i set up anything timezone stuff in my yamls

Comment: Base on your spec above and the error message you have **only 1 node** (right?). If you updated your deployment with nodeSelector or nodeAffinity before, remove them and it should run.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `name:` is missing under `volumes:` in the deployment manifest. Can you try the following in the deployment manifest:

```
  volumes:
    - name: nginx-claim
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: nginx-claim
```

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-pod) is the documentation.

Comment: I changed it but it states the same. Its pointing to spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name, do I need to do something with the template?